# BLoC is returning an empty snapshot. BLoC stream is from Sqflite

Tags: flutter, snapshot, bloc, sqflite

I'm trying to update my listview widget from BloC but it's always returning an empty snapshot.BLoC is using a stream from an async SQLite query using sqflite. The sqflite query appears to be working when accessed directly.

Here's a snippet of the UI portion:

```
ListBloc listBloc = ListBloc();

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(child: getBoxList()),
            FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                listBloc.queryBoxes();
              },
              child: Text('pull data'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


  Widget getBoxList() {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: listBloc.boxes,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Box>> snapshot) {
          return getList(snapshot);
        });
  }

  Widget getList(AsyncSnapshot<List<Box>> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Text(snapshot.data[index].boxName);
        },
      );
    } else {
      return Text('snapshot has no data');
    }
  }
```

Hers's a snippet of the BloC:

```
class ListBloc {

  final _boxListController = StreamController<List<Box>>.broadcast();

  final DatabaseHelper _db = DatabaseHelper.instance;


  get boxes => _boxListController.stream;

  ListBloc() {
    getAllIBoxes();
  }


  getAllIBoxes() async {
    _boxListController.sink
        .add(await _db.queryAllBoxRows(DatabaseHelper.tableBoxes));
  }



  dispose() {
    // _itemListController.close();
    _boxListController.close();
  }
}
```

`_db.queryAllBoxRows(DatabaseHelper.tableBoxes)` works just fine when tested outside the BLoC.

Thank you!

-- update --

here's the queryBoxes function in BLoC. I just added this to test if the query returns data.

```
queryBoxes() async {
    DatabaseHelper _db = DatabaseHelper.instance;
    final _boxes = await _db.queryAllBoxRows(DatabaseHelper.tableBoxes);
    _boxes.forEach((element) {
      print(element.boxName);
    });
  }
```

-- update 2 --

Source of the stream:

```
getAllIBoxes() async {
    _boxListController.sink
        .add(await _db.queryAllBoxRows(DatabaseHelper.tableBoxes));
  }
```

is `_db.queryAllBoxRows(DatabaseHelper.tableBoxes)` which is a method in my DatabaseHelper that looks like this.

```
Future<List<Box>> queryAllBoxRows(table) async {
    Database db = await instance.database;

    final _result = await db.query(table);
    List<Box> box = _result.map((e) => Box.fromDatabaseJson(e)).toList();
    return box;
  }
```

Comment: Where is your `queryBoxes` function? I didn't see that anywhere in that ListBloc

Comment: You are not sending that values through your stream

Answer (score 0):

You are just printing the values in the `queryBoxes` function. You have to inform your stream that there is data available, for that you've to add the values to the sink.

Modify your function to:

```dart
queryBoxes() async {
   DatabaseHelper _db = DatabaseHelper.instance;
   final _boxes = await _db.queryAllBoxRows(DatabaseHelper.tableBoxes);
   _boxes.forEach((element) {
      print(element.boxName);
   });
   _boxListController.sink.add(boxes);
}
```

Comment: Sorry if this part of my post is not clear. This section is just mean to test the _db.queryAllBoxRows method if it will return some data. The real source of my stream is 

_db.queryAllBoxRows(DatabaseHelper.tableBoxes);

which points to a method in my DatabaseHelper:

Future<List<Box>> queryAllBoxRows(table) async {
    Database db = await instance.database;

    final _result = await db.query(table);
    List<Box> box = _result.map((e) => Box.fromDatabaseJson(e)).toList();
    return box;
  }

Comment: @chippy Whatever your source may be, you have to add the result to the sink. In the comment above also I'm not seeing any relevant code which sets the data to the stream.